# Palpatine's Insider - Knowledge About Anakin Spying

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, darth-sidious

Before his speech regarding Darth Plagueis, Sheev Palpatine and Anakin Skywalker have a conversation regarding the Jedi "overthrowing" the Republic and betraying Palpatine.

How does he know this?  It is simply his Force vision?  Or would he have knowledge of this through some other means?  Listening devices?  Other Dark Jedi in the Jedi Temple?

Comment: Well, the Jedi *weren't* planning to overthrow anyone, so are you asking how was Palpatine claiming to know of a Jedi plot (had there actually been one)?

Comment: You may not have noticed before, but Palpatine isn't exactly the most truthful guy around.

Comment: yeah.  that;s why I put the word "overthrow" in parentheses...I know at this point his is manipulating Anakin's feelings but how would he know explicitly that Anakin was asked personally to spy for the jedi?

Comment: To add to this, he knows about Padme and Anakin's situation with her pregnancy.  I know Anakin refers to Palpatine as a "friend" and "mentor" when he is first asked to betray the Jedi Code and spy for the Council.  I can't imagine Anakin would say anything to anyone though...so again, is it just that Palpatine dark side powers allow him more precise clairvoyance?

Comment: Maybe it was simply foreknowledge of the fact that given his intended course of action, the Jedi were bound (by honor and duty and all that) to *try* and stop him.  More the *"I won't tell him the important bit about why they'll be **entirely justified** in that action, just describe the action.. Mua-ha-ha"*

Comment: I thought that too.  Palpatine would know the rules regarding the Jedi Code, i'm guessing, and knowing how the move would irk the Jedi, perhaps he just played his hand that way...

Comment: *"I thought that too."*  You thought what?  Tip: Add @phantom42 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry @AndrewThompson, i meant your last comment before mine...the one I just upvoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that was basically **his** plan.

- Eventually, Jedi find out he's a Sith
- They make a move against him. That is really the only option they would have
- He accuses them of treason **and executes Order 66**.

Please note that this plan is necessary, in advance, or he'd have no excuse for Order 66!

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the plan he has.  That much is obvious.  But specifically knowing that the Jedi asked Anakin to spy, it was almost too specific a detail for me to not have some other method of obtaining that information.  But...logically, it does work.  "If i appoint Anakin and not a master on the council, they will be suspicious of my reasoning, and will want to know what i am up to...hence Anakin, hence, I will plant the seed of distrust in Anakin.."  I guess I should take into account that he is THE Sith...

Comment: He befriended Anakin with the dire intent to turn him. He know that Anakin was impulsive and couldn't fully control his feelings and thus was not only exceptionally strong with the force but also rather easy to influence. The coucils decsions while prudent actually played right into Palpatine's hands.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven - yep, that's what I was driving at. He knew what they are doing because he manipulated them into doing just what he wanted.

Comment: Palpatine _knew_ the Jedi didn't trust him, that's why he ask _Anakin_, a very imperfect Jedi, to represent him on the council. He was _counting_ on the Jedi to use this opportunity to spy on him since he knew they'd frown on his interfering in the council's affairs.